# Grouped Product Display a sum of all associated products stock

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products, stock-status

I search everywhere but cannot find a good answer.

In my 1.9 magento rwd theme, I set for single product to display the stock qty after stock status, but when i put some simple products to a grouped product type then in the table of grouped products I can see the correct stock qty and in main window i see and is display for total group stock qty = 0

This is my code:

> rwd\default\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <br></br>
    <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Cantitate disponibila :') ?> <span><!--<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>--><?= (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?></span> <?php echo $this->__('buc.') ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Cantitate disponibila :') ?> <span><!--<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>--><?= (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty()?></span> <?php echo $this->__('buc.') ?>
        </p>
        <?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span></br><?php echo $this->__() ?><span style="color:#0b9817;text-align:center;">Stoc Furnizor</span></br><span style="color:#de4231;text-align:center;">Comanda telefonic 0785.737.227</span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('COD PRODUS: ') ?><?php echo $_product->getSku() ?><br/>
    <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('transport_01') ?>
```

Please see the image:
[image]

Can someone help me or to display total stock of asociated products or to hide only the main stock code.???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the configurable product in Magento doesn't store the sum of all the stocks related to its simple associated products.

A quick win solution could be to hide the main stock qty by changing the initial condition from:
`<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>`

to

`<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus() && ($_product-> getTypeId() != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)): ?>`

Alternatively, you should sum all the stock quantities for every simple product

> This for configurable products

```
$totalStock = 0;
foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product) as $simpleProduct) {
    $simpleStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleProduct)->getQty();
    $totalStock += $simpleStock;
}
```

> This for grouped products

```
$totalStock = 0;
foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product) as $simpleProduct) {
    $simpleStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleProduct)->getQty();
    $totalStock += $simpleStock;
}
```

But performance-wise this is not optimal, as it loads a product model for each associated product.

So, your final code could be

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
        <?php
        $productStock = 0;
        if ($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
            foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product) as $simpleProduct) {
                $simpleStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleProduct)->getQty();
                $productStock += $simpleStock;
            }
        } elseif ($_product->getTypeId() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED) {
            foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product) as $simpleProduct) {
                $simpleStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleProduct)->getQty();
                $productStock += $simpleStock;
            }
        } else {
            $productStock = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
        }
        ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
            <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Cantitate disponibila :') ?> <span><!--<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>--><?= $productStock ?></span> <?php echo $this->__('buc.') ?></p>
        <?php else: ?>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Cantitate disponibila :') ?> <span><!--<?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?>--><?= $productStock?></span> <?php echo $this->__('buc.') ?></p>
            <?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
            <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span></br><?php echo $this->__() ?><span style="color:#0b9817;text-align:center;">Stoc Furnizor</span></br><span style="color:#de4231;text-align:center;">Comanda telefonic 0785.737.227</span></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('COD PRODUS: ') ?><?php echo $_product->getSku() ?><br/>
    <?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('transport_01') ?>
```

Comment: Enzo Perrotta - if i use: <?php if($_product->isSaleable() && ($_product->getProductType() != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE): ?> the i will broke my theme, because disapear all butons and righr bar.

Comment: also Enzo Perrotta, if i use the second code - nothing happen, it's like begin, no change.

Comment: My fault. Try hiding the stock status by replacing 
`<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>`
with  

`<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus() && ($_product->getProductType() != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)): ?>
`

Comment: i replace the code and is accepted by theme, but don't change anything. Is like in my initial photo. Any other idea?

Comment: Also, the second snippet of code contained a mistake...I apologize, now it's fixed. Have a look if it works as intended

Comment: no, is not work. i try it both solutions and no change. Hmm... or i do something wrong...

Comment: I am sorry: `$_product->getProductType()` must be `$_product->getTypeId()` for both the solutions..

Comment: No, i'm sorry but still not work. The code is accepted, but don't modify nothing.

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes, i clear the magento cache and also the browser cache! :)

Comment: Let's continue in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/97665/discussion-about-question-285970?tab=general)

Comment: i cannot... because they ask me 20 reputation to talk in chat... :))) and i'm new on network :(

Comment: Can you post the code you implemented after all my advices?

Comment: <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <br></br>
        <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus() && ($_product-> getTypeId() != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE)): ?>
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>

Comment: i cannot answer you with the full code... is another way to can talk with you, like messenger or team viewer?

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and add there the new code..

Comment: i add the new code on your initial sugestion, because in can't add in a comment or inital post edit.

Comment: Got it, however, I am going to remove your additions to my answer. I tested it locally and it works as expected.

Comment: hmm.. i dont know what to say, in this moment i use your code... and is no diference (Please see example at: https://www.magazinulupeste.ro/fir-guta-nylon-pescuit/berkley-fir-textil-whiplash-8-galben-150mt)

Comment: Can you try writing an arbitrary text as the value of `$productStock`? Place something like `<?php $productStock = 999; ?>` Just above `<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>`  and check if it's displayed

Comment: Ok, I got it why it's not working.. That product is not a configurable one, it's a Grouped one.
Give me a moment to rework the fix...

Comment: hmm... it's a good idea and i do so, but... now in the grouped product for total stock is displayed corectly, but when do you enter to see the simple product (example click on the first one from list, same link) the simple product now it have also 999 stock. So in not quite a solution. --== :)) yes is a grouped product.

Comment: Solution updated

Comment: wow... thank you verry much! it's work great.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97683/discussion-on-answer-by-enzo-perrotta-grouped-product-display-a-sum-of-all-assoc).